# Add industry, company size and role to Jobs RSS Feed

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, rss

The RSS feed on https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed currently returns a XML like this one:

```xml
<item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">150823</guid>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/150823/senior-front-end-javascript-engineer-canva?a=OA2JwzUk2wU&amp;so_medium=Talent&amp;so_source=TalentApi</link>
    <a10:author>
        <a10:name>Canva</a10:name>
    </a10:author>
    <category>javascript</category>
    <category>typescript</category>
    <category>mobx</category>
    <category>reactjs</category>
    <title>Senior Front-End JavaScript Engineer at Canva (Sydney, Australia)</title>
    <description>&lt;p>&lt;strong>About Us &lt;/strong>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;p>&lt;span>At Canva, our mission is to democratize design, empower creativity and visual expression for every person, on every platform. Since launch in April 2013, our user base has grown exponentially, amassing millions of monthly active users in over 100 languages, making us one of the world's fastest-growing technology companies. &lt;/span>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;p>&lt;span>Engineering is a core part of who we are. The team takes pride in its focus on engineering fundamentals. We strive to use the most appropriate tools for the tasks at hand, and to strike a measured balance between getting things done and long term maintainability. Engineers frequently host sessions where a new idea or software engineering practice is discussed &amp;mdash; this ensures that everyone in the team is constantly learning.&lt;/span>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;p>&lt;span>We work hard to get our fundamentals right across the business. Consequently, the frontend code base is constantly being improved and optimised so new features can be implemented easily. We also have a flat structure where engineers are invited to comment on the direction their peers are taking on features. When a new feature is being built, engineers review each other&amp;rsquo;s code; this ensures that knowledge is shared and it doesn&amp;rsquo;t need to be reworked.&lt;/span>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;p>&lt;span>At Canva you can be part of a company that is growing rapidly, building a product that users love.&lt;/span>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;p>&lt;strong>&lt;strong>Responsibilities&lt;/strong>&lt;/strong>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;ul>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Work with product designers &amp;amp; managers, Fullstack and Backend Engineers to build a next-generation web application with a focus on an extraordinary client-side experience&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Build efficient and reusable front-end abstractions and systems&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Identify and address performance bottlenecks&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Participate in design and code reviews&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Help to identify and communicate standard practices and methodologies for front-end engineering&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Interact with our back end systems&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;/ul>&lt;br />&lt;p>&lt;strong>&lt;strong>Requirements&lt;/strong>&lt;/strong>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;ul>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Knowledge of JavaScript and web technologies (HTML/CSS)&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Experience developing rich applications with HTML/CSS/JS&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Intimate knowledge of cross-browser and cross-device development&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Ability to write high-performance, reusable code for UI components, including appropriate testing&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Passion for performance debugging and benchmarking&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Minimum two years experience&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>BS or MS degree in Computer Science / Software Engineering or a related field&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;/ul>&lt;br />&lt;p>&lt;strong>&lt;strong>Bonus experience&lt;/strong>&lt;/strong>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;ul>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Experience with SVGs&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Experience with graphics programming&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Experience with GLSL / WebGL&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Experience with Java&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Experience with Typescript, React &amp;amp; MobX&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>An interest in interaction design&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;/ul>&lt;br />&lt;p>&lt;strong>&lt;strong>Benefits&lt;/strong>&lt;/strong>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;p>&lt;span>It is important to us that we create a workplace that you love coming to.&lt;/span>&lt;/p>&lt;br />&lt;ul>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Competitive salary, plus equity options&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Flexible working hours, we mean it when we say we value work-life balance&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>In-house chefs that cook delicious breakfast and lunch for us each day&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Free Gym and Yoga &lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Generous parental leave policy&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>Pet-friendly offices&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;li>&lt;span>We offer a full relocation package (including visa)&lt;/span>&lt;/li>&lt;br />&lt;/ul></description>
    <pubDate>Wed, 28 Jul 2021 09:45:39 Z</pubDate>
    <a10:updated>2021-07-28T09:45:39Z</a10:updated>
    <location xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/">Sydney, Australia</location>
</item>
```

Can you please include also the job's industry, company size and role?